# Export Canvas content to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on something using HTML5 Canvas.
It's all working great, except right now, I can export the canvas content to PNG using Canvas2image. But I would like to export it to PDF. I've made some research and I'm pretty sure it's possible...but I can't seem to understand what I need to change in my code to make it work. I've read about a plugin called pdf.js...but I can't figure out how to implent it in my code.

First part :

```
function showDownloadText() {
        document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("textdownload").style.display = "block";
    }

    function hideDownloadText() {
        document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("textdownload").style.display = "none";
    }

    function convertCanvas(strType) {
        if (strType == "PNG")
            var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas, true);
        if (strType == "BMP")
            var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas, true);
        if (strType == "JPEG")
            var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas, true);

        if (!oImg) {
            alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving " + strType + " files!");
            return false;
        }

        oImg.id = "canvasimage";

        oImg.style.border = oCanvas.style.border;
        oCanvas.parentNode.replaceChild(oImg, oCanvas);

        showDownloadText();
    }
```

And the JS to that saves the image :

```
    document.getElementById("convertpngbtn").onclick = function() {
        convertCanvas("PNG");
    }

    document.getElementById("resetbtn").onclick = function() {
        var oImg = document.getElementById("canvasimage");
        oImg.parentNode.replaceChild(oCanvas, oImg);

        hideDownloadText();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use 2 plugins for this: 
1) [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)
2) [canvas-toBlob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js)

Then add this piece of code to generate light weight PDF:

```
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imgSrc = url.createObjectURL(blob);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgSrc;
    img.onload = function () {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [img.height, img.width]);
        pdf.addImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        pdf.save(fileName + '.pdf');
    }; 
});
```

Comment: **Alternatively, but on in the same theme**: If you use `jspdf.min.js` in jsPDF's `dist` folder, you can send `canvas.toDataURL()` into `pdf.addImage` so you don't directly need `canvas-toBlob.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/385045/export-html5-webpage-including-canvas-to-pdf
- http://badassjs.com/post/708922912/pdf-js-create-pdfs-in-javascript

Most probably it will do the work you need

Comment: The first link look very intresting. The thing is that it doesnt seem to be saving the Canvas content. The Canvas has nothing in it at the beginning. Only after the page loads it draws the background, but at first it's blank. So it saves a PDF of a blank canvas. And for the second link, it saves the text and links only, not the images yet...(If I understood correctly). Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This jspdf is only useful in saving the file in the browser but we can't use that PDF generated to send to the server