# HTML5 canvas to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working in HTML5 and using canvas as a designing tool. However, I want to save my canvas in a jpeg file with a default of image/png and I want to show the preview of my canvas in a PDF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201679/export-canvas-content-to-pdf

Comment: I have gone through that link which @paul thinks give the solution for my query. But I have gone through the entire solution for that question but did nt get a feasible solution.Hence I am asking here to get a particular and working solution.

Answer (score 24):

A good approach is to use a combination of jspdf.js and html2canvas.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 
  <button id="download">Download Pdf</button>
```

```
html2canvas($("#canvas"), { onrendered: function(canvas) {         
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
  doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
  doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4s5k59s/1222/

Tested in Google Chrome 38, IE11 and Firefox 34.
For Safari you might need to change the image format from PNG to JPEG.

Comment: @Blizzard, that is the perfect example.  Simple, actuated by a button, easy to understand.  (Why isn't that top of the examples at github for jspdf?) Easily displayed in jsfiddle.  Many thanks.

Comment: This library doesn't seem to be updated any more, this crashes on my browser, and there are multiple open issues regarding crashes.

Comment: Thanks Ashu. I have fixed the fiddle. The issue was that the jsPDF resource has been moved.

Comment: Man (@Blizzard ) , I am using html2Canvas to Capture my screen , and been looking for download the canvas into pdf , I appreciate your way ( Same mind : )