# Export multiple charts and tables into 1 PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, charts, pdf-generation

I'm looking for 2 JS libraries for generating charts and PDFs. I've already tested some, but none of them has satisfied my needs so far.

#### Background:

I need to create **several independent charts and tables** in order to export all of them afterwards into **1 PDF**.

#### What I already tried:

I have already tested [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/), but they don't seem to work the way I need them.

*highcharts* offers the possibility to create a chart and a table, showing the same data. So same input visualized differently.
[Nobody could help me here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169455/charts-and-tables-within-one-chart-with-different-data).

With *amcharts* I could export multiple charts, but the problem with the tables remained the same: They only can display the same content in different ways.
[Nobody could help me here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680338/create-independent-charts-and-tables).

Both libraries provide an own export function. However, when creating a custom HTML table (`<table><tr>...`), I need to use an extern PDF library, in my case it was [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf). That way I can export my custom tables, but the charts won't be exported properly anymore.
[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmtkwz6w/).

#### Question:

Does anybody know a way or another library, so that I can properly **export multiple charts and tables into 1 PDF**?

Comment: Www.cloudformatter.com is a library with external formatter that can do that. Supports svg native without canvas

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** sorry they are using SVG not canvas. So maybe you can find a way how to convert svg to an image.

I think the problem is that jspdf cannot handle html-canvas proberly.
You could try to convert the canvas to an image with html2canvas and feed it to jspdf.

Have a look here:
[Html5-canvas to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699366/html5-canvas-to-pdf)

Copied from the answer:

```
html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {         
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
            'image/png');              
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }
});
```