# Optimize output of HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, svg, html2canvas

I created a chart with [amchart](https://www.amcharts.com/). I will later have to export it as PDF.
As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891575/export-multiple-charts-and-tables-into-1-pdf/41892218#41892218), I need to convert the chart first into SVG with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

It works, but the chart looks "broken":

[image: chart]

Is there any way to optimize the result?

Here is an extract of my code:

```
   /* --- Chart --- */

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", {
  "type": "serial",
  // ...
});

/* --- HTML2Canvas --- */

$('#cmd').click(function() {
  html2canvas($("#output"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
})
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/az3tx0y3/).

*PS: I know, there is a built in export function for every chart. The reason I can't use it, is that in the real case, there will be more content to export (several charts, tables, text, etc.), so that I need to export an entire DIV.*

Comment: Have you try my solution?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried  a lot of solution, but the most i have found is to use a script for convert **[SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595847/javascript-convert-html-div-with-svg-to-image)** (Thanks **@Kaiido**) and use `html2canvas` plugin.

I generated your chart and `onclick` event i assign **ID** to the **SVG** tag created.

After click on the button the **SVG** transform this to **Canvas**. Now you can just make what you want with this.

Please try bellow in full screen mode for show your label totally

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", {
   "type": "serial",
   "theme": "light",
   "dataProvider": [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2025
   }, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
   }, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
   }, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
   }, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
   }, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
   }, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
   }, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
   }, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
   }, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
   }, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
   }, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
   }, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395
   }],
   "valueAxes": [{
  "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "gridAlpha": 0.2,
  "dashLength": 0
   }],
   "gridAboveGraphs": true,
   "startDuration": 1,
   "graphs": [{
  "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
  "fillAlphas": 0.8,
  "lineAlpha": 0.2,
  "type": "column",
  "valueField": "visits"
   }],
   "chartCursor": {
  "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
  "cursorAlpha": 0,
  "zoomable": false
   },
   "categoryField": "country",
   "categoryAxis": {
  "gridPosition": "start",
  "gridAlpha": 0,
  "tickPosition": "start",
  "tickLength": 20
   },
   "export": {
  "enabled": true
   }

 });

 $('#cmd').click(function() {
  $("svg").attr("id","svg") //Assign ID to SCG tag
  
  // without converting the svg to png
  html2canvas(chartdiv1, {         // chartdiv1 is your div
   onrendered: function(can) {
     //dirty.appendChild(can);
   }
    });
    
  // first convert your svg to png
  exportInlineSVG(svg, function(data, canvas) {
    svg.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, svg);
    // then call html2canvas
    html2canvas(chartdiv1, {       // chartdiv1 is your div
   onrendered: function(can) {
     can.id = 'canvas';
    // clean.appendChild(can);
   }
    });
  })


  function exportInlineSVG(svg, receiver, params, quality) {
    if (!svg || !svg.nodeName || svg.nodeName !== 'svg') {
   console.error('Wrong arguments : should be \n exportSVG(SVGElement, function([dataURL],[canvasElement]) || IMGElement || CanvasElement [, String_toDataURL_Params, Float_Params_quality])')
   return;
    }

    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    var clone;
    // This will convert an external image to a dataURL
    var toDataURL = function(image) {

   var img = new Image();
   // CORS workaround, this won't work in IE<11
   // If you are sure you don't need it, remove the next line and the double onerror handler
   // First try with crossorigin set, it should fire an error if not needed
   img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

   img.onload = function() {
     // we should now be able to draw it without tainting the canvas
     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     var bbox = image.getBBox();
     canvas.width = bbox.width;
     canvas.height = bbox.height;
     // draw the loaded image
     canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, bbox.width, bbox.height);
     // set our original <image>'s href attribute to the dataURL of our canvas
     image.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href', canvas.toDataURL());
     // that was the last one
     if (++encoded === total) exportDoc()
   }

   // No CORS set in the response  
   img.onerror = function() {
    // save the src
    var oldSrc = this.src;
    // there is an other problem
    this.onerror = function() {
     console.warn('failed to load an image at : ', this.src);
     if (--total === encoded && encoded > 0) exportDoc();
      }
      // remove the crossorigin attribute
    this.removeAttribute('crossorigin');
    // retry
    this.src = '';
    this.src = oldSrc;
     }
     // load our external image into our img
   img.src = image.getAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href');
    }

    // The final function that will export our svgNode to our receiver
    var exportDoc = function() {
     // check if our svgNode has width and height properties set to absolute values
     // otherwise, canvas won't be able to draw it
     var bbox = svg.getBBox();
     // avoid modifying the original one
     clone = svg.cloneNode(true);
     if (svg.width.baseVal.unitType !== 1) clone.setAttribute('width', bbox.width);
     if (svg.height.baseVal.unitType !== 1) clone.setAttribute('height', bbox.height);

     parseStyles();

     // serialize our node
     var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(clone);
     // remember to encode special chars
     var svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);

     var svgImg = new Image();

     svgImg.onload = function() {
    // if we set a canvas as receiver, then use it
    // otherwise create a new one
    var canvas = (receiver && receiver.nodeName === 'CANVAS') ? receiver : document.createElement('canvas');
    // IE11 doesn't set a width on svg images...
    canvas.width = this.width || bbox.width;
    canvas.height = this.height || bbox.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // try to catch IE
    try {
      // if we set an <img> as receiver
      if (receiver.nodeName === 'IMG') {
     // make the img looks like the svg
     receiver.setAttribute('style', getSVGStyles(receiver));
     receiver.src = canvas.toDataURL(params, quality);
      } else {
     // make the canvas looks like the canvas
     canvas.setAttribute('style', getSVGStyles(canvas));
     // a container element
     if (receiver.appendChild && receiver !== canvas)
       receiver.appendChild(canvas);
     // if we set a function
     else if (typeof receiver === 'function')
       receiver(canvas.toDataURL(params, quality), canvas);
      }
    } catch (ie) {
      console.warn("Your ~browser~ has tainted the canvas.\n The canvas is returned");
      if (receiver.nodeName === 'IMG') receiver.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, receiver);
      else receiver(null, canvas);
    }
     }
     svgImg.onerror = function(e) {
    if (svg._cleanedNS) {
      console.error("Couldn't export svg, please check that the svgElement passed is a valid svg document.");
      return;
    }
    // Some non-standard NameSpaces can cause this issues
    // This will remove them all
    function cleanNS(el) {
      var attr = el.attributes;
      for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
     if (attr[i].name.indexOf(':') > -1) el.removeAttribute(attr[i].name)
      }
    }
    cleanNS(svg);
    for (var i = 0; i < svg.children.length; i++)
      cleanNS(svg.children[i]);
    svg._cleanedNS = true;
    // retry the export
    exportDoc();
     }
     svgImg.src = svgURL;
   }
   // ToDo : find a way to get only usefull rules
    var parseStyles = function() {
   var styleS = [],i;
   // transform the live StyleSheetList to an array to avoid endless loop
   for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
     styleS.push(document.styleSheets[i]);
   // Do we have a `<defs>` element already ?
   var defs = clone.querySelector('defs') || document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
   if (!defs.parentNode)
     clone.insertBefore(defs, clone.firstElementChild);

   // iterate through all document's stylesheets
   for (i = 0; i < styleS.length; i++) {
     var style = document.createElement('style');
     var rules = styleS[i].cssRules,
    l = rules.length;
     for (var j = 0; j < l; j++)
    style.innerHTML += rules[j].cssText + '\n';

     defs.appendChild(style);
   }
   // small hack to avoid border and margins being applied inside the <img>
   var s = clone.style;
   s.border = s.padding = s.margin = 0;
   s.transform = 'initial';
    }
    var getSVGStyles = function(node) {
   var dest = node.cloneNode(true);
   svg.parentNode.insertBefore(dest, svg);
   var dest_comp = getComputedStyle(dest);
   var svg_comp = getComputedStyle(svg);
   var mods = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < svg_comp.length; i++) {
     if (svg_comp[svg_comp[i]] !== dest_comp[svg_comp[i]])
    mods += svg_comp[i] + ':' + svg_comp[svg_comp[i]] + ';';
   }
   svg.parentNode.removeChild(dest);
   return mods;
    }

    var images = svg.querySelectorAll('image'),
   total = images.length,
   encoded = 0;
    // Loop through all our <images> elements
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   // check if the image is external
   if (images[i].getAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href').indexOf('data:image') < 0)
     toDataURL(images[i]);
   // else increment our counter
   else if (++encoded === total) exportDoc()
    }
    // if there were no <image> element
    if (total === 0) exportDoc();
  }
 })
})
```

```css
#chartdiv1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.amcharts-export-menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.js"></script>

<button id="cmd">HTML2Canvas</button>
<div id="output">
  <div id="chartdiv1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of html2Canvas button add jQuery code to add height and width as attribute to your svg element (add as attribute and not in style) and it will export in exact format

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same, and fix this by changing the SVG width and height. Here is the code used to fix the issue.

```
function printOptions(type = 'before') {
    var svg = chart.div.querySelector('svg');
    if (svg) {
       if (type == 'after') { // remove the attributes after generating canvas
          svg.removeAttribute('width');
          svg.removeAttribute('height');
       } else { // set width and height according to parent container
          svg.setAttribute('width', chart.div.clientWidth);
          svg.setAttribute('height', chart.div.clientHeight);
       }
       chart.validateNow(); // validating am chart again.
     }
}    
// code for download image
downloadImage() {
   printOptions();
   html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart-div')).then(canvas => {
      printOptions('after');
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
      a.download = 'Report.png';
      a.click();
    });
 }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/ermxhg93/)**, you can comment printOption before converting the image for the exported image changes.