# Export AMCharts to PPT

Tags: c#, jquery, export, amcharts, html2canvas

I want export AMCharts to PPT. I have 7-8 charts on one screen and I want to export PPT.

I tried many ways but not working.
Also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41937337/6629154) but not working for me.

I want this kind of result [ExpedctedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX2FJ.png)
but i am getting [GeneratedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjIZb.png)

Missing chart lines and pie chart need help to solve this problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $("#html-content-holder"); 
    var getCanvas;

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {           
        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
            }
        });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var pptx = new PptxGenJS();
        var slide = pptx.addNewSlide();
        slide.addImage({
            x: 1, y: 1, w: 8.0, h: 4.0,
            data: imgageData
        });
        pptx.save('Dealer-Performance-Dashboard');
        return false;

    });
});

<div class="row dashselection" id="html-content-holder">
</div>
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview" />
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
<br />
<h3>Preview :</h3>
<div id="previewImage">
</div>
```

from [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/) you will get any chart script

Comment: please provide your code