# Download html output as an image

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, datatables, export

I am new to front end programming and I need to **download/export** the html output as an image or PDF.

Lets say I have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Front Side</h3>
        <div class="studentcard-frontside">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
            <div class="student-detail">
                <p>Student Name: <span>Bilal Zafar</span></p>
                <p>Father Name: <span>Zafarullah Khan</span></p>
                <p>Date of Birth: <span>9th March, 1991</span></p>
                <p>Address: <span>House # 12, Street # 43, Islamabad</span></p>
                <p>If Found, <span>Please call +92-333-152</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and after some styling on this div, it looks like a student identity card as shown below:

[image]

Now what I want, I need two buttons download as an image and PDF and print this specific card.
Is there any way I can convert this html output to image and PDF ?

I have google and I found **dataTables jquery**, It works with tables perfect But i don't know how to use it in this scenario.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have tried first and at what point you are getting stuck.

Comment: @BilalZafar Have you tried my answer below???

Answer (score 0):

You could use html2canvas (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to render the DOM element to a hidden canvas and then use this: [HTML5 canvas to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699366/html5-canvas-to-pdf) to export it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the example usages about [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) on [jQuery DataTables and ASP.NET MVC Integration](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/155422/jquery-datatables-and-asp-net-mvc-integration-part) page with all of the parts (from Part I to Part VI).

Answer (score 0):

There is in most modern browsers no longer a need for anything other than CSS, (JavaScript free, "embed" images and its CORS free too). This is a modern vanilla  HTML ability, to click a button and then let user print the download as PDF. What is needed is styling to include a page size, background colours (or images) and hide the button during print. All those can be within the HTML style head. (Here removed heading and altered buttons appearance for illustration, but can be removed for printing).

[image]

To restrict media size use appropriate values this is simply an example (not the one used above) it can be as simple or as complex as required to alter PDF appearances, colours, dimensions and styling, independent of default HTML screen appearance.

```
<head>
<style>
@media print {
  @page {
    /* For different margins – use the standard CSS margin property: north, east, south, west, here it is one value */
    margin: 0;
    /* Browser default, customisable by the user if using the print dialogue. */
    size: auto;
    /* Different width and height. here using desired width="600" height="300" can be px or pt or cm. For square, just use one value or use name like A6 landscape; note this is over-riding any above size: but we need to bump up for browser rounding*/
    size: 600px 300px;
  }
  body { margin: 0; }
}
</style>
</head>
```

```
<input class="hidden" type = "button" value = "Print this Downloaded HTML to PDF" onclick = "window.print()" />
```

Result NOT a canvas but true searchable PDF

[image]